# Is it a bad idea to store movies on website in MP4 format?

Tags: mp4, avi, movie, mpeg

I am posting this question with hope that somebody will migrate it to more appropriate Stackexchange site if Stackoverflow this question does not sastisfly the rules. I could not find a better place.

My question is what is wrong with MP4 movie files? What conflicts a developer to convert movies to mp4 and store them on website with such format? I see majority of movies on website are in AVI, MPEG. However, I was going to convert some of the movies to MP4 and and store them on my website with this format. Is there something wrong with it? I mean films, size of 800 MB+.

Thanks.

Comment: Potential copyright issues aside... No.

Comment: Do you mean I might get involved in leggal issues if I just convert AVI or MPG to MP4? It sounds new and strange to me, probably because I live in a country where such issues are really very rare. Please tell me couple of words more about it.

Comment: Not necessarily, no. There is nothing inherently wrong with the MP4 format. It's not going to attract server goblins, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: What causes you to think there's anything wrong with MP4?

Answer (score 0):

MP4 is most widely supported format, so personally its best format to strore VOD content.

its supported by

IOS
android
flash
silverlight
HTML5

so it covers majority of screens.